# JVM args from spring-boot are not applied to tomcat

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, tomcat9

I need to do some remote debugging of a java web app running on tomcat9. I followed the instructions here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.6.RELEASE/maven-plugin/examples/run-debug.html and modified my pom.xml to include

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <jvmArguments>
                    -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005
                </jvmArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I compiled the project with

> mvn clean package

, copied the WAR to the remote server, and restarted Tomcat with a systemctl command. When I tried to actually connect to the debug port however, the connection failed. Looking at the output of the server logs, it doesn't seem as though those JVM args were actually applied. In the logs I get the following output:

```
[2023-08-11 14:00:53] [info] NOTE: Picked up JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS:  --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
[2023-08-11 14:00:54] [info] Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/9.0.58 (Ubuntu)
[2023-08-11 14:00:54] [info] Server built:          Jan 6 1970 15:09:28 UTC
[2023-08-11 14:00:54] [info] Server version number: 9.0.58.0
[2023-08-11 14:00:54] [info] OS Name:               Linux
[2023-08-11 14:00:54] [info] OS Version:            5.19.0-1027-aws
[2023-08-11 14:00:54] [info] Architecture:          amd64
[2023-08-11 14:00:54] [info] Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
[2023-08-11 14:00:54] [info] JVM Version:           11.0.20+8-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu122.04
[2023-08-11 14:00:54] [info] JVM Vendor:            Ubuntu
[2023-08-11 14:00:54] [info] CATALINA_BASE:         /var/lib/tomcat9
[2023-08-11 14:00:54] [info] CATALINA_HOME:         /usr/share/tomcat9
[2023-08-11 14:00:54] [info] Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
[2023-08-11 14:00:54] [info] Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
[2023-08-11 14:00:54] [info] Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
[2023-08-11 14:00:54] [info] Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED
[2023-08-11 14:00:54] [info] Command line argument: --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
[2023-08-11 14:00:54] [info] Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/var/lib/tomcat9/conf/logging.properties
[2023-08-11 14:00:54] [info] Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
[2023-08-11 14:00:54] [info] Command line argument: -Djava.awt.headless=true
[2023-08-11 14:00:54] [info] Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
[2023-08-11 14:00:54] [info] Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
[2023-08-11 14:00:54] [info] Command line argument: -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027
[2023-08-11 14:00:54] [info] Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
[2023-08-11 14:00:54] [info] Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/var/lib/tomcat9
[2023-08-11 14:00:54] [info] Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/usr/share/tomcat9
[2023-08-11 14:00:54] [info] Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp
[2023-08-11 14:00:54] [info] Loaded Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.31] using APR version [1.7.0].
```

Just to be sure I wasn't missing something, I also used the ps command on the running application and got the following results:

```
tomcat    205443       1  2 14:00 ?        00:00:36 /usr/lib/jvm/default java/bin/java 
-Djava.util.logging.config.file=/var/lib/tomcat9/conf/logging.properties 
-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager 
-Djava.awt.headless=true 
-Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 
-Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources 
-Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027 
-Dignore.endorsed.dirs= -classpath /usr/share/tomcat9/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat9/bin/tomcat-juli.jar 
-Dcatalina.base=/var/lib/tomcat9 
-Dcatalina.home=/usr/share/tomcat9 
-Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
```

I don't see any indication that the additional JVM args I supplied to spring-boot were actually applied. I'm at a bit of a loss here. Is the spring-boot-maven-plugin not the correct way to specify these args? The only other way I know of would be to modify the Catalina.sh, but then I wouldn't be able to disable the debugging without editing the file again.

Comment: I expect those instructions are aimed at the case where you are running tomcat within/bundled into the self-contained spring boot application. If you build a WAR then those JVM settings are not going to have any effect on the tomcat where that WAR is deployed. Your options are to run the application as standalone with bundled tomcat and debug that, or else update the `catalina.sh` of the Tomcat you are deploying to.